# Insert into database byte[0] as a varbinary datatype parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, varbinary

This is a simple program that creates a test database with a single table containing two columns of type `VARCHAR(50)` and `VARBINARY(8000)`. I want to save an empty array (`byte[0]`) in the `varbinary` column, but after program executes, the `BINVAL` column contains an array of 8000 null bytes instead of an empty array.

How can an empty byte array be saved in a `varbinary` column?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static string connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=True;database=master";
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sqlCommandParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
            ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand("Use master; CREATE DATABASE TestDB", sqlCommandParams);
            ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand("USE TestDB; CREATE TABLE SampleData (STRVAL VARCHAR(50), BINVAL VARBINARY(8000))", sqlCommandParams);
            sqlCommandParams.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@STRVAL",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Value = string.Empty
            });
            
            sqlCommandParams.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@BINVAL",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Binary,
                Value = new byte[0]
            });
            
            ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(
                "USE TestDb INSERT INTO SampleData (STRVAL, BINVAL) VALUES (@STRVAL, @BINVAL)", 
                sqlCommandParams);
        }
        
        public static void ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(string command, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> commandParams)
        {
            try
            {
                using( var conn = new SqlConnection(connString) )
                {
                    using( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = command;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(commandParams.ToArray());
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use SqlDbType.VarBinary instead

Comment: @Crowcoder you're right, I've missed SqlDbType.VarBinary. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably better to use `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @user9939 No, null is not the same as empty value.

Comment: Agreed. It's not the same. You may want to rethink your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `VarBinary` not `Binary`. I would also advise you to specify the length of the parameter.

Furthermore, you should probably just change the database you are connecting to, rather than a `USE` statement.

You shouldn't hard-code the connection string, put it into a settings file. Then you can use `SqlConnectionBuilder` to change the database to `master` for the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

And you should just use a new list of parameters for each command. You could even use a `params` array.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
       
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Properties.ConnectionString);
            connBuilder.Database = "master";
            using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString))
                ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(conn, "CREATE DATABASE TestDB");

            ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand("CREATE TABLE SampleData (STRVAL VARCHAR(50), BINVAL VARBINARY(8000))");
            
            ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(
                "INSERT INTO SampleData (STRVAL, BINVAL) VALUES (@STRVAL, @BINVAL)", 
                new SqlParameter("@STRVAL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) {
                    Value = string.Empty
                },
                new SqlParameter("@BINVAL", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1) {
                    Value = new byte[0]
                });
        }
        
        public static void ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(string command, params SqlParameter[] commandParams)
        {
            using( var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.ConnectionString) )
                ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(conn, command, commandParams);
        }

        public static void ExecuteParametrizedDbCommand(SqlConnection conn, string command, params SqlParameter[] commandParams)
        {
            try
            {
                using( var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn) )
                {
                    if(commandParams != null)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(commandParams.ToArray());
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```